# Using Xampp and 'git' for team web development in wordpress. Database issue

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, git, xampp

me and a coworker are trying to move a website from a test server to local web development. Our boss wants us to use Amazon web services CodeCommit in conjunction with Xampp to do this. We have made progress but cannot overcome a database issue. Here is what we have done.

Set up AWS accounts and recieved necessary credentials from boss for the sites repo

Pulled repo and ensured that we could both commit and pull normally

Downloaded xampp, made sure apache and php were functioning normally

Now, one of us (me) has used the duplicator wordpress plugin to backup the site and load it into a local version.

I can now develop locally fine and push changes, all images and pages from the site are showing up locally

**ISSUE:**
How can my coworker also develop locally, the issue appears to be that he has not made a database in xampp phpmyadmin control panel for the site, but if he did wouldnt it be a different one than I am using, and thus wouldnt sync with git properly? Where xampp stores the database info isnt in the git folder, so I may be doing it wrong as well!

We cannot figure out the correct course of action, please if you can point us in the right direction. Much appreciated!!

Comment: I would say the best solution would be a online database to make this, otherwise you have different local databases what is not recommendable. The best way is to use an online copy of the productive database

Comment: You don't add your database to Git - to work locally its easiest to just have your own copies. Your changes will be to code - this is what gets updated in Git.